# Discord.js display the number of bans in status

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a bot that's for a specific server and I want to set the status to the number of bans the server has.

I have the following code, but I can't get the `banned.size`:

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
  message.guild.fetchBans().then(banned => {
    let sizee = banned.size
  })

  setInterval(function() {
    let lol = ['status 1', `status 2`, `Status 3`, `status 4`, `this guild has ${sizee} banned users `];
    let f = ['LISTENING', 'WATCHING', 'LISTENING', 'PLAYING', 'WATCHING'];
    let status = lol[Math.floor(Math.random()*lol.length)];
    client.user.setActivity(status, {type: f[Math.floor(Math.random()*f.length)]})
  }, 15000) 
  
  client.user.setPresence({ status: 'online' })

  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have or receive a `message` object on the `ready` event so you can't get the guild from that. You will need to find the guild by its ID. `client.guilds.cache.get()` should do the trick.

Once you have the guild, you need to move [`fetchBans()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchBans) to the callback in [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), so it fetches it every single time. If you fetch it outside of it, it will only fetch once when you start the bot and it won't be updated unless you restart your bot.

Instead of struggling with `then`s, you can use an async function and just `await` the result.

The following example will work if you add your guild ID. I've added some comments too:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  // get the guild once the bot is ready
  // make sure you add the guild id
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('ADD GUILD ID HERE');

  client.user.setPresence({ status: 'online' });

  // run the updateStatus function every 15s
  // we need to pass the client and guild
  setInterval(updateStatus, 15000, client, guild);

  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

// helper function to pick a random element from an array
function pickOne(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

// async function that fetches the current number of bans
// and updates the status
async function updateStatus(client, guild) {
  const bans = await guild.fetchBans();
  const statuses = [
    'status 1',
    'status 2',
    'status 3',
    'status 4',
    `this guild has ${bans.size} banned users`,
  ];
  const activities = [
    'LISTENING',
    'WATCHING',
    'LISTENING',
    'PLAYING',
    'WATCHING',
  ];

  client.user.setActivity(pickOne(statuses), {
    type: pickOne(activities),
  });
}
```

PS: One improvement would be to only fetch the bans when you want to show it in the status.